# Xcode: compile 64bit app with 32bit library

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, 64-bit, static-libraries

My iOS app makes use of an external accessory. I added some new functionality to the app and some new artwork. When I submit the app to Apple, I get a warning that all apps submitted to the App Store need to support 64 bit as of February 1.

To make the accessory work, I use a library provided by the manufacturer, which is only compiled for 32 bit. I was able to use this library because I made my app 32 bit as well. As of February 1, however, I won't be able to submit any updates, because of the 64 bit requirement.

I suppose the only way is to request the manufacturer to provide me with a 64 bit version of his library, or is there any way around this to make my app 64 bit compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to compile a 64-bit application with a 32-bit library. You will need to obtain a 64-bit version of the library.